# Sort array using another array as input

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to sort the following array using another array provided bellow.

For example. I have the following array:

```
[note] => Array
(
   [0] => 'note1'
   [1] => 'note2'
   [2] => 'note3'
), 
[text] => Array
(
   [0] => 'text1'
   [2] => 'test3'
), 
[year] => Array
(
   [0] => '2002'
   [1] => '2000'
   [2] => '2011'
)
```

And I have the array:

```
$sortBy = array('2011', '2000', '2002').
```

I would like to sort the above array according the values of $sortBy array.

The desired result is:

```
[note] => Array
(
   [0] => 'note3'
   [1] => 'note2'
   [2] => 'note1'
), 
[text] => Array
(
   [0] => 'test3'
   [2] => 'text1'
), 
[year] => Array
( 
   [0] => '2011'
   [1] => '2000'
   [2] => '2002'
)
```

Comment: @hakre, are you sure? I don't think it's suitable.

Comment: @rambocoder: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11022569/367456 - this is multisort (and could additionally benefit from the `array_flip` mapping you make use of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array:

```
$array = array(
    'note' => array('note1', 'note2', 'note3'),
    'text' => array('text1', 'text2', 'text3'),
    'year' => array('2002', '2000', '2011')
);
```

And the order of something:

```
$sortBy = array('2011', '2000', '2002');
$sortOrder = $array['year'];
```

You then find out how the year needs to be sorted:

```
array_walk($sortOrder, function(&$v) use ($sortBy) {$v = array_search($v, $sortBy);});
```

To then sort the whole array based on that order:

```
array_multisort($sortOrder, $array['note'], $array['text'], $array['year']);
```

Full example:

```
$array = array(
    'note' => array('note1', 'note2', 'note3'),
    'text' => array('text1', 'text2', 'text3'),
    'year' => array('2002', '2000', '2011')
);
$sortBy = array('2011', '2000', '2002');
$sortOrder = $array['year'];
array_walk($sortOrder, function(&$v) use ($sortBy) {$v = array_search($v, $sortBy);});
array_multisort($sortOrder, $array['note'], $array['text'], $array['year']);
```

Output/[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MUlDAV):

```
Array(
    [note] => Array(
            [0] => note3
            [1] => note2
            [2] => note1
        )
    [text] => Array(
            [0] => text3
            [1] => text2
            [2] => text1
        )
    [year] => Array(
            [0] => 2011
            [1] => 2000
            [2] => 2002
        )
)
```

*Edit:* The mapped variant, spares the `array_search`:

```
$sortBy = array_flip(array('2011', '2000', '2002'));
$sortOrder = $array['year'];
array_walk($sortOrder, function(&$v) use ($sortBy) {$v = $sortBy[$v];});
array_multisort($sortOrder, $array['note'], $array['text'], $array['year']);
```

*Edit2:* PHP 5.2 wrapped into a single function, full parametrization:

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string|int $by key/offset
 * @param array $order
 * @return array
 */
function array_multisort_by_order(array $array, $by, array $order)
{
    $order = array_flip($order);
    $params[] = $array[$by];
    foreach($params[0] as &$v) $v = $order[$v];
    foreach($array as &$v) $params[] = &$v; unset($v);
    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $params);
    return $array;
}

// Usage:
array_multisort_by_order($array, 'year', array('2011', '2000', '2002'));
```

Comment: I get Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent.

Comment: For which of the many examples? And take case your array as all the same number of values per each sub-array.

Comment: I used the function you provided at the end and each sub-array *does not have* the same number of values.

Comment: Oh well, then what do you expect? That an algorithm can actually guess how n elements match onto m elements where n != m? I'd say there's something broken in your question and actually PHP was so nice to highlight you that with an error message ;) - joke aside, you should specify how to deal with that in your question. From your question it looks like that you have always the same number of elements.

Comment: Hm. Fortunately, the result is just fine. Without any errors. I will edit my question a bit to take a look. Please take a look now and observe that some values might be missing.

Comment: But your code works really well because I can observe in the resulted array: `[page-end] => Array ( ) [pages] => Array ( [0] => 213--234 [3] => 247-259 )` which means that it behaves correcty when a sub-array has no elements eg `[page-end]` or not all the elements eg `[pages]`. Can I somehow remove the warning?

Comment: There is the error suppression (control) operator `@`, but I normally won't recommend it. You can just add it in front of anything and it silences all errors therein. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: where should I place that in your method?

Comment: `@call_user_func_array` which will suppress the message for `array_multisort` which is used as callback therein as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a function for it like this:

```
function sort_by($arr, $sub, $order){
    // Create a map from old key to new key
    $value_kmap = array_flip($arr[$sub]);
    $sort_kmap = array_flip($order);
    foreach($order as $value)
        $kmap[$value_kmap[$value]] = $sort_kmap[$value];

    // Create your result array
    foreach($arr as $name => $sub_arr)
        foreach($kmap as $key => $new_key)
            if(isset($sub_arr[$key]))
                $result[$name][$new_key] = $sub_arr[$key];

    return $result;
}
```

The function is generic making no reference to `year`. It takes in the name of the sub array to sort by as an argument. You would use it like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'note' => array('note1', 'note2', 'note3'),
    'text' => array('text1', 'text3'),
    'year' => array('2002',  '2000',  '2011' )
);

print_r(sort_by($arr, 'year', array('2011', '2000', '2002')));
```

Outputs [[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/wjjdKIZ1)]:

```
Array
(
    [note] => Array
        (
            [0] => note3
            [1] => note2
            [2] => note1
        )

    [text] => Array
        (
            [1] => text3
            [2] => text1
        )

    [year] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011
            [1] => 2000
            [2] => 2002
        )

)
```

Comment: technically this doesn't do what was asked, because you reindexed the numeric keys. in reality, that's probably desired though.

Comment: @rambocoder Ah, I hadn't noticed the keys were reordered too in the example output.

Comment: @salamis Do you need the keys reordered as well, or is this what you want?

Comment: no mate that's ok . but I have a slight problem if a value is missing. for example if year[2] is defined but note[2] it is not. So it might be better to have the keys.

Comment: Sorry mate. Another problem that I found is when a value in the array for sorting does not appear in the original array

Comment: @salamis I'm not sure why those are problems. They weren't in the question, anyways why would you try sorting by non-existant values and how would you determine the order if values are missing?

Comment: @salamis Anyway, just needed to add `if(isset($sub_arr[$key]))` to make it work with your updated input.

Answer (score 0):

I am naming your array to be sorted as $haystack.

```
$newArray = array(); // not necessary, but starts your new array
// you know how you want to sort it, so loop through your sorting array
foreach( $sortBy as $year ){ 
   // get the key of the 2nd level of the 2D array, which we are saving as $k
   foreach( $haystack['year'] as $key => $value ){
      if( $value == $year ) $k = $key;
      break; // since we got what we need, we don't need to let this foreach loop finish
      // you could also do an array_search() here instead of this foreach
   }
   if( $k > 0 ){
      // if k is 0, we didn't find that value so we're not going to sort it or include it in the new array
      foreach( $haystack as $key => $a ){ 
         // just save it into a new array
         $newArray[$key][$k] = $a;       
      }
   }
}
var_dump( $newArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

untested(you should provide var_export() of your array when you post these kinda questions)

```
//$orig = ...

$sorted = array();

$map = array_flip($orig['year']);
foreach ($sortBy as $year) {
    $originalNumerickey = $map[$year];
    foreach ($orig as $stringKey => $subArray) {
        $sorted[$stringKey][$originalNumerickey] = $subArray[$originalNumerickey];
    }
}
```