# Sort array using another array of values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array depicting points accumulated during the year. As a tie breaker on equal points, I have another value that I calculate that I want the result to be sorted on.

This is the sorted array, showing points during the year:

```
$results = [
  1 => 220
  0 => 209
  4 => 127
  14 => 89
  3 => 84
  7 => 78
  2 => 71
  13 => 61
  16 => 56
  8 => 48
  12 => 45
  10 => 42
  11 => 42
  6 => 39
  5 => 35
  9 => 32
  15 => 22
  17 => 22
  18 => 22
  19 => 1
```

Because indexes 10 and 11, and 15, 17 and 18 are equal, they need to be sorted by the lowest values in the following array:

```
// For 10 and 11
$anotherArray = [
  11 => 101
  10 => 119
]

// For 15, 17 and 18
$anotherArray = [
  17 => 150
  18 => 160
  15 => 179
]
```

So the resulting array should look like this:

```
$finalArray = [
  1 => 220
  0 => 209
  4 => 127
  14 => 89
  3 => 84
  7 => 78
  2 => 71
  13 => 61
  16 => 56
  8 => 48
  12 => 45
  11 => 42
  10 => 42
  6 => 39
  5 => 35
  9 => 32
  17 => 22
  18 => 22
  15 => 22
  19 => 1
]
```

How would I achieve this?

EDIT: It's not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021814). The solution suggested is based on the values of an array and does not solve the issue where I need to insert values in another array in the correct order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array using another array as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021814/sort-array-using-another-array-as-input)

Answer (score 0):

A 2-dimensional array is created with the values of the result array and the values of the 'anotherArrays'.
This array is sorted with uasort () and converted back into a one-dimensional array.

```
$results = [
  1 => 220,0 => 209,4 => 127, 14 => 89, 3 => 84, 7 => 78,
  2 => 71, 13 => 61, 16 => 56, 8 => 48, 12 => 45, 10 => 42, 11 => 42,
  6 => 39, 5 => 35, 9 => 32, 15 => 22, 17 => 22, 18 => 22, 19 => 1
];

$anotherArray1 = [11 => 101, 10 => 119];
$anotherArray2 = [17 => 150, 18 => 160, 15 => 179];

$sekArr = array_replace($results,$anotherArray1,$anotherArray2);

$newArr = [];
foreach($results as $key => $value){
  $newArr[$key] = ["v" => $value, 's' => $sekArr[$key]];
}

uasort($newArr, function($a,$b){
  return $b['v'] <=> $a['v'] ?: $a['s'] <=> $b['s'];
});

$results = [];
foreach($newArr as $key => $arr){
  $results[$key] = $arr['v'];
}

var_dump($results);
```

Try for yourself: https://3v4l.org/Si6ST